# How to access pandas series nested within a dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

The json response is listed as below:

```
[{
"ID": "12345",
"Date": "9-11-19",
"Term": "Fall",
"Details": [{
    "Version": "v2",
    "Release": "Series-2",
    "Rate": "Quarterly",
.
.
.

    }]
}]
```

I believe it's a Series because I get the following in the terminal

```
print(type(df['Details']))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

How do I get to Version, Release, Rate or any data within the Details series? I've tried

```
1) df['Details'].get('Rate') #this always gives me None
2) df['Details']['Rate'] # KeyError: 'Rate'
3) df['Details'].tolist() #list can only accessed by indices not strings
```

Unless I made a typo in one of my numerous earlier attempts (the 3 above are the only ones I could Undo via Ctrl + Z) I don't why I'm having such an issue. In the end what I want to do is drop rows from the df based upon Rate values. Should I convert the df to some other type?

Comment: How about flattening your DataFrame: `from pandas.io.json import json_normalize; json_normalize(data, ['Details'], meta=['ID', 'Date', 'Term'])`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
df['Details'][0]['Rate']
```

I think it is stored as a Series containing a single dict.

Comment: that gives `TypeError: string indices must be integers` b/c 'Rate' must be an integer

Comment: What does `df['Details'].iloc[0]` give you?